# _CastError (Null check operator used on a null value) in Provider flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-animation, dart-pub

I am getting data from my server and then calling a notifier to popup notification but when I call a provider on it then he will get me a null check operator error. What to do next?

```
class OrderBranches with ChangeNotifier {
  static List<OrderBranch> _items = [];
  static List<OrderBranch> _soldOrders = [];

  List<OrderBranch> get items {
    return [..._items];
  }

  Future<void> fetchOrderBranches() async {
    try {
      var url = basicURL + 'orderBranch/';
      // print('url');
      // print(url);
      final responseData =
          await MyRequest.callGet(url, headers, 'fetchOrderBranches');
      // final responseData = json.decode(response.body);
      // _items.clear();
      responseData.forEach((item) {
        addOrderBranchAndDependents(item);
      });
      notifyListeners();
    } catch (e) {
      print('Error');
      print(e);
    }
  }


  static void addOrderBranchAndDependents(Map<String, dynamic> localMap) {
    OrderBranch orderBranch = await classMapToObj(orderBranchData);
    bool found = false;
    // if order status is opened and it is notifiable then show notification
    bool branchNotificationFlag = orderBranchData['Branch_Notification'];

    String orderStatus = orderBranchData['Order']['OrderStatus']['Name'];
    if (orderBranch.orderBranchStatusName == 'Pending' &&
        orderStatus == 'Opened' &&
        branchNotificationFlag == true) {
      await changeBranchNotificationFlag(orderBranch.id);
     
        var notifierProvider =
            Provider.of<Notifier>(confContext, listen: false);
        notifyOrderNotification(
            notifierProvider,
            orderBranch.slug,
            'New order from Ommino',
            'Tap here to get details of your new order, by Ommino');
  }

}
```

Comment: var notifierProvider =
            Provider.of<Notifier>(confContext, listen: false);, in this line when i call provider then it is getting an error

Comment: It usually throws that error if you used a  ! operator on a nullable value. Can you please provide the entire error message?

Comment: its error message was this "_CastError (Null check operator used on a null value)" and then i figured it out that it was the problem in the context which i have passed in it. I handled this case by adjusting the context of it.